# Ordering events in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a construct like this.......

```
<div id="right_top_block" class="drop_head">
    <div id="right_top_block_head" class="dropper block_head rounded-corner">
        Friends
    </div>
    <div class="box_container">
        <div id="box_list" class="drop_list">
            <ul id="right_top_ul">    
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I removed the inner contents as it is too lengthy... and i have a jquery like this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.drop_head').each(function(i, e) {
        $('.dropper', e).click(function() {
            $('.drop_list', e).slideToggle(1500);
        });
    });

    $('.dropper').click(function(e) {
        $(e.target).parent().removeClass('leaf_class');
        if ($(e.target).parent().height() < 300) $(e.target).parent().addClass('leaf_class');
    });
});
```

Now what happens is, each time the dropper is clicked, a leaf class is added to the right_top_block and then a slideDown(as part of slideToggle) on the correspoding drop_list is done( I have many such).... Now if it is clicked again the leaf class is removed from the right_top_block and then a slideUP(as part of slideToggle) on the corresponding drop_list is performed. But what i really want is, when a slideUp is performed, i want the slideToggle to complete and then i want the leaf_class to be removed. How do i change the order of the event execution? I guess due to the delay 1500 i am specifying in the toggle is the cause for this. While don't want to loose the slow transition that it gives, i want that to be completed and then the leaf class to be removed. How do i do this?

Comment: Can you fix the indenting of your code?  Very hard to read.

Comment: sorry about that.... fixed it....

Comment: Your code was an _absolute_ mess. You can't just post badly formatted code up here and expect people to read it. I've edited it this time, but please, in the future do it yourself.

Comment: sorry about the indentation, but i corrected it myself (my first edit)? what was wrong? OK any way thanks, I am looking forward for a solution guys...

Comment: my initial post is dumb, i accept. But seriously guys.. enough editing. now i need a solution. The code looks fine now... please look into the code and help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, two remarks about the code in your question:

- The code that runs on `click` is split into two event handlers: one responsible for the slide animation and the other for the class change. That's quite confusing and actually makes the problem *more* complex. It would be easier if these two handlers were merged into one, or if one handler was performing the whole `slideDown()` operation sequence and the other the whole `slideUp()` sequence.
- You're using `e.target` with an element that doesn't seem to contain any descendant from where a `click` event would bubble up. That's perfectly valid in itself, but using `this` instead would be shorter and make your intent clearer.

Now, let's look at your requirements. It looks like you want `leaf_class` to be added *before* the `slideDown()` animation starts, but only removed *after* the `slideUp()` animation completes.

You can achieve that in a simpler way with a pair of handlers bound to the [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) event, and explicit calls to [slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) and [slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) instead of [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/).

```
$('.dropper').toggle(function() {
    var $dropHead = $(this).parent();
    $dropHead.addClass("leaf_class");
    $(".drop_list", $dropHead).slideDown(1500);
}, function() {
    var $dropHead = $(this).parent();
    $(".drop_list", $dropHead).slideUp(1500, function() {
        $dropHead.removeClass("leaf_class");
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, your code works fine. But i can't understand what this line means:  `$(".drop_list", $dropHead).slideDown(1500);` is it something like selecting a drop_list class which has a parent specified by dropHead? I tried to search the jqeury api for selectors but didn't find anything. And just out of curiosity, is it not possible to delay an events propagation if we wish to?

Comment: @sasidhar, I'm passing `$dropHead` as the *context* argument to the [$()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) function. It's equivalent to writing `$dropHead.find(".drop_list").slideDown(1500);`. I'm afraid I don't understand the second part of your comment, can you clarify what you mean by `delay an events propagation`?

Comment: What i mean by delaying an event propagation is, say i have two event handlers for the same event(like my first code), now what i want is, the second handler must be invoked after some delay. One might say i could make the second event handler a function and call it after the specific delay using timeout in the first event handler. But i am interested to know if i can do have the event propagation delayed like this and also is there a guaranteed ordered in which the event handlers are called? (I have my own reasons to have such needs). Is this possible?

Comment: @sasidhar, event handlers are always called in the order they've been bound to the element. To my knowledge, it's not possible to delay the subsequent handlers (only to cancel them with [stopImmediatePropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/)). Using a function and `setTimeout()` is indeed the way I would solve that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood what you're asking, then you're looking for a callback function to your `slideToggle` function:

```
$('.drop_list', e).slideToggle(1500, function() {
    //Do stuff after slide is complete
});
```

The callback function is executed upon completion of the slide animation. See the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) for more information.

Comment: but there is a different event object that i use in the second function... how do i do the same stuff in the callback function??